# Why does a recordset "MoveLast" take longer on a recordset with fewerrecords?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function I call to extract the records of certain fields:

```
Public Function fun_rstlast(str_input As String, str_field As String) As Variant

    Set rst = dbcOC.OpenRecordset(str_input, dbOpenSnapshot)
    rst.MoveLast

    fun_rstlast = rst.Fields(str_field)

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

It is in a series of loops, so pulls the same sequence of records but from two sets of identical tables (yes I know, but I want to keep it that way for now). The annoying thing is that for some reason it takes 10 times longer to run the function from the first set of tables than the second set of tables. I've looked at the recordsets and the one from the faster table is actually 2x larger!

Here's the section of code that does the looping:

```
            Set col = New Collection

            str_DATE_G = "DATE_S"

            arr_field(1) = "DATE_S"
            arr_field(2) = "LATITUDE_T"
            arr_field(3) = "LONGITUDE_T"

            For r = 1 To UBound(arr_ID)

                lng_ID = arr_ID(r)

                For f = 1 To UBound(arr_field)

                    str_field = arr_field(f)

                    'debug.Print "str_field: " & str_field

                    ' Create query string
                    str_input = "SELECT * " _
                        & " FROM (tbl_G_stats_" & tour & " INNER JOIN tbl_G_ov_" & tour _
                        & " ON tbl_G_stats_" & tour & ".PK_G = tbl_G_ov_" & tour & ".PK_G)" _
                        & " INNER JOIN tours_" & tour & " ON tbl_G_ov_" & tour & ".ID_T = tours_" & tour & ".ID_T" _
                        & " WHERE Clng(" & str_DATE_G & ") < " & lng_DATE_G _
                        & " AND tbl_G_stats_" & tour & "." & str_ID_A & " = " & lng_ID

                    secs1 = Timer()

                    var_rstlast = fun_rstlast(str_input, str_field)

                    secs2 = Timer()

                    'debug.Print "var_rstlast: " & var_rstlast

                    Debug.Print "Timer: " & lng_ID & " " & str_field & " " & (secs2 - secs1) * 1000

                    col.Add var_rstlast

                Next f

            Next r
```

There's another loop much further back that's alternates between the 2 sets of tables (`tour`).

Worth mentioning that I investigated the indexes and data types of the two tables and everything is identical.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: This can be because of many reasons, the most common one being table fragmentation, which you can fix with a compact & repair. The question is not reproducible as-is.

Comment: You sir are awesome :-) C&R fixed it. Two things: i) I assume this is the database equivilent of turning it of and on again? ii) stick this as the answer and get the reputation!!

Comment: Note that your `str_input ` does not depend on `str_field`, meaning the query returns the same on every call. You could move that part out of the `For j` loop.

Comment: ...I mean `for f` loop.

Comment: @Jossy I've added a quick explanation as an answer. If you want to know more, you can google _index fragmentation_, and encounter a lot of SQL server articles about it. Access is somewhat similar, but unfortunately doesn't allow us to rebuild indexes without a complete compact and repair, and doesn't allow us to specify fill factor or get fragmentation statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for varying performance is table/index fragmentation.

To fix table fragmentation in Access, you can execute a compact & repair. Compact & repair moves all tables as a whole to a new location, then removes the old tables, removing all table fragmentation in the process, and often avoiding file fragmentation too.

Table fragmentation commonly occurs when updating text data after it's been inserted (since the text data might be longer than the original data) and when manually inserting data in primary key fields. There are more causes, though.

If you experience table fragmentation often, Access offers a *Compact on close* setting in the database settings menu. However, this comes at a substantial delay when closing the database.